# I'm trying to crreate sign-in with google popup using GooglAuthProvider() class in firebase and its giving me error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using `onClick` to call the popup function, whenever i click on a button it gives me the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Please check the code.

```
const SignIn = () => {
  const logGoogleUser = async () => {
    const response = await signInWithGooglePopup();
    console.log(response);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>SignIn Page</h1>
      <button onClick={logGoogleUser}>Sign in with Google Popup</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't recognize `signInWithGooglePopup` as a built-in API. How is that defined, or where do you import it from?

Comment: " signInWithGooglePopup" is the arrow function name, Exactly I'm using "signInWithPopup" google provider from firebase/auth.

Comment: What I mean is that I don't see that function defined anywhere here: https://firebase.google.com/s/results?q=signInWithGooglePopup. So likely it's either something you defined in your project or you got it from another library. Either way, we'll need to see the code/link to that library in the question - as nothing in the code you shared is calling `create` on a property that can be `undefined`.